# What do the different symbols on level select mean?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-q-force

When choosing a level to play or looking at your Hero Profile, you can see for each level three symbols: A Medal, signifying which of the three level medals (or just one on the last level) you've earned (Completion, all generators, time); A Gold Bolt, signifying how many Gold Bolts you've collected.

Additionally, there's a circle with pointed edges. I have no idea what it signifies. It looks like a the symbol for skill points, but I can't tell what are the level's skill points. Does it count the skill points available only on that level? (like the "time trials" skill points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After expirimenting some more I can confirm that these represent level-specific Skill Points, these are:

For the levels Markazia, Ebaro, Proteus VII, Ebaro v2(=Snow Storm): (7 Skill Points each)

- **The Savior of *X*** - Take every node and complete the level without dying.
- **Protector of *X*** - Finish the level with every generator standing.
- **Speed Run Olympian/Expert/Novice** - Complete *X* in *{time}* or less.
- **Crate Hater: *X*** - Destroy All Crates on *X*.
- **The Insomniac Challenge: *X*** - Beat Dev Challenge Time in *X* in *{time}* or less. [These Skill Point are secret]

(Where *X* is the level name and *{time}* is the appropriate time for the level/challenge)

For the final level (2 Skill Points, both secret):

- **The Bully** - Defeat Zurgo without taking any damage.
- **Insomniac Challenge: Stuart Zurgo** - Beat Dev Challenge Time in the final fight in 08:26 minutes or less.